# mongoose query count and return some of result list

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

API looks like:

```
{
  list: [], // length should lower than 20
  total: 160 // for frontend pagination
}
```

here is my code:

```js
    const queryInstance = someModel.find(query)
    total = await queryInstance.countDocuments()
    list = await queryInstance.sort({ date: -1 }).skip(offset * pageSize).limit(pageSize * 1)
    return { total, list }
```

looks like the first await change the `queryInstance`, result is `list` equals `total`.

should my code must like:

```js
   total = await someModel.find(query).countDocuments()
   list = await someModel.find(query).sort({ date: -1 }).skip(offset * pageSize).limit(pageSize * 1)
```

is this query the database twice? should I worry about this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you query the database twice . What you can do is an aggregate with $match for your (query) and $sortByCount (for you count and sort) and after that you can do something like this :

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([match,sortByCount,skip,limit])
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortByCount/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/

Comment: Thanks for your help! `sortByCount` must spicify a field, that's not my need. I need count all doc match query, and the return some of it.  ```const user = '5ecba430f072fc41302c8549'
const queryPublic = {
  delete: false,
  isPrivate: false,
  user: {$not: {$eq: user}},
}

const querySelf = {
  delete: false,
  user,
}

;(async function aa () {
  const query = momentsModel.aggregate([
    {$match: {$or: [querySelf, queryPublic]}},
    {$sortByCount: '$_id'}
  ])
  query.exec().then(data => console.log(data)).catch(console.error)
})()```